# simple jquery code optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey i'm relativly new to jquery and i've a simple question. I have these two selections and functions, they work fine, but i'm sure it could be written better. How do i combine these two tasks in one?

```
$('li').attr('data-li', function(index) {
    return index;
});

$('nav div').attr('data-div', function(index) {
    return index;
});
```

I've two different selectors, but a nearly identical method, but the problem is that the .attr method has a different argument otherwise i would have written a variable like this.

```
var ind = $(this).attr('', function(index) {
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function and pass it as callback, this is plain js. In javascript you can declare functions and pass them around. The code would look something like this:

```
function getIndex(index) { return index }

$('li').attr('data-li', getIndex);
$('nav div').attr('data-div', getIndex);
```